# Convert List(Of T) to BindingList(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list:

```
Dim _lineItems As List(Of LineItemEncounter)
```

Is there a way to convert this to a BindingList?

Comment: The BindingList constructor will take an `IList` param.  They are 2 different collections, so you cant "convert"

Comment: You cannot convert it like Plutonix already wrote. But you can create a new BindingList based on the List: `Dim _boundLineItems As New BindingList(Of LineItemEncounter)(_lineItems)`